# Splitting string to array in bash with long delimiter

Tags: arrays, bash, macos, ifs

Using bash in Terminal on OSX, this code:

`newtext="FIRST<br><br>SECOND<br><br>THIRD"
IFS='<br><br>' read -ra text_array <<< "$newtext"
printf "%s\n" "${text_array[@]}"`

outputs:

> FIRST
> SECOND
> THIRD>

Why does the array have so many newline elements? If I use single-character delimiters it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IFS` can split string on each of the single character only and when you provide `<br><br>` it splits input on `<`, `b`, `r` and `>`.

You can use this work-around to get your job done:

```
s="FIRST<br><br>SECOND<br><br>THIRD"
del=$'\5'   # our arbitrary delimiter; can be any other control character
IFS="$del" read -ra arr <<< "${s//<br><br>/$del}"
declare -p arr
```

```
declare -a arr='([0]="FIRST" [1]="SECOND" [2]="THIRD")'
```

- `del=$'\5'` sets delimiter to control character `\5`. `\5` is just an arbitrary character and it can be replaced with any other character that is not present in input.
- `"${s//<br><br>/$del}"` replace `<br><br>` with control character `\5`
- `IFS="$del"` splits input on `\5` while populating array